# Simple helper method for JUnit3 tests

Tags: java, android, exception-handling

In `JUnit 3`, I cannot tell `JUnit` what type of exception is expected. In `JUnit 4`, the declaration `@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)` does it.

But, unfortunately in `Android development`, I can use only `JUnit 3`. So I wrote this simple method:

```
public class TestingUtils {

    public static void assertExpectedException(
                           Class<? extends Exception> exceptionClass, Runnable runnable) {
        try {
            runnable.run();
            throw new AssertionFailedError(
                         "Expected exception: <" + exceptionClass.getName() + ">");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!exceptionClass.equals(e.getClass())) {
                throw new AssertionFailedError(
                        "Expected exception: <" + exceptionClass.getName() + "> " +
                        "but was: <" + e.getClass().getName() + ">"
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
public void testConstructorThrowsExceptionIfArgumentIsNull() {
    TestingUtils.assertExpectedException(IllegalArgumentException.class, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SomeTestedClass(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The message for the case if it is was *not* thrown should be clearer, including something like "Expected exception X, but was not thrown".

Comment: FYI, I have done [something similar in JDOM](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/test/src/java/org/jdom2/test/util/UnitTestUtil.java#L305) and [I use it like this](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/test/src/java/org/jdom2/test/cases/TestElement.java#L3281).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have [been though this loop before](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/test/src/java/org/jdom2/test/util/UnitTestUtil.java#L305). I chose to do things in a slightly different way to you, in that instead of creating a Runnable, I instead add a try/catch block to the actual test.

Each system has pros/cons, but the differences are really cosmetic. Using a `Runnable` does make the JUnit logic better contained in the utility code.... but makes calling the utility test code a little bit more complicated. I am not sure which one I prefer.

I have a suggestion regarding this line here:

```
if (!exceptionClass.equals(e.getClass())) { ....
```

It is useful to be able to expect a super-type of an exception. For example, you want to trap an `SQLException` when you run a query, or you want to trap an `IOException` when you do something on a Stream..... you have the code:

```
TestingUtils.assertExpectedException(SQLException.class, ....);
```

but, the actual exception may be `com.ibm.db2.jdbc.xxx.PicnicException`, which is a subclass of SQLException.

Using `equals()` to match the exceptions is a problem.... you should use:

```
if (!exceptionClass.isInstance(e)) {....
```

One other thing, which is android specific.....

I found a [bug in the Android Dalvik implementation/SDK](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29378) relating to this problem... you **should** be setting the 'cause' for your AssertionError so that it is logged correctly. Unfortunately, the bug (which is fixed in Jelly-Bean) makes this impossible.

If you are sure you will be testing on Jelly-Bean or newer (the bug *was fixed* a while ago), you should also be initializing the cause on your AssertionError:

```
            AssertionFailedError tothrow = new AssertionFailedError(
                    "Expected exception: <" + exceptionClass.getName() + "> " +
                    "but was: <" + e.getClass().getName() + ">"
            );
            tothrow.initCause(e);
            throw tothrow;
```